# Over riding the inline CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I have a tree structure, where I can expand and collapse the node. Each node is assigned inline CSS height   top and left. The top and left are dynamically calculated during the render based on the position of the node. I want to reduce the height of the node to `40px` and also reduce the top and the left for each node by a `20px` * position of node. How can I achieve this with the CSS? I do not have access to directly change in the code where the calculation is happening. The only way allowed to modify is from the CSS file.

example:

```html
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 62px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 124px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 186px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 248px;"></div>
```

These are the inline CSS applied for the top for each node. I want each node's top to be reduced by 20* index of node. 1st node as it is, 2nd by 20, 3rd by 40, 4th by 60 and so on.

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

Updated:

Would this be possible with Scss or less?

Comment: you're using a lot of inline css - you should add it as css to make it more manageable

Comment: This is applied from a custom written library. I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

you can write an external CSS file to do that just like this:

```
.node{
    height: 40px!important;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This code will do your work but don't forget to give `!important` in the CSS codes lines. `!important` will overwrite the inline CSS if there is the same CSS parameter in the external CSS file.

Note: Inline CSS will not be removed just will not work against the external CSS. So do not worry. Just go to your external CSS file and give the new codes there with `!important`.

If you don't want to use `!important` you can use this code below it will also work properly.

```
.node{
    max-height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you want to prevent using !important you can use css propertys wich are not used inline but solve your problem like "max-height"

Comment: Thank you for your comment I've updated the answer as you recommended

Comment: I want the first div to be having margin-top as 0, 2nd as -20, 3rd as -40, 4th -60 and so on. With the above solution all the divs are applied the same margin-top of -20.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the only way to override an inline attribute directly from a CSS stylesheet is to use `!important`. Another option is to use other properties that constrain or change the behavior.

In this case you can use a negative `transform: translate()` or `margin` to move the nodes up and to the left, and constrain the height with `max-height`.

You can use `:nth-child()` to select the node/s that you want to change:

```css
.node {
  max-height: 50px;
}

.node:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0, -20px);
}

.node:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-20px, -20px);
}

.node:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-40px, -20px);
}

.node:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate(-60px, -20px);
}

.node:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate(-80px, -20px);
}

/** just for the example **/
.node {
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  left: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 62px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 124px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 186px;"></div>
<div class="node" style="height: 62px; position: absolute; top: 248px;"></div>
```

Comment: transform works fine when I want all the divs to move by the same constant. In my case I would need the first div to be moved by 0, 2nd by -20, 3rd by -40, 4 by -60 and so on. How can I change to achieve that ?

Comment: If the nodes are know, you can use css `:nth-child()`. If not, you'll need to set the style via JS. See updated answer.